# Convert variable of dtype=<U14 to standard list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm reading values from a csv using pandas and I've come across a format I've never seen before, to give an example:

myval = array('[1.0, 0, 0, 0]', dtype='<U14')

I would like to convert myval into a list of integers/ floats, but nothing I try seems compatible with a variable of this datatype. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: `lst = json.loads(str(myval))` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is unicode 14 characters, you can try:

```
eval(myval)
```

Comment: Tried this and was greeted with this error: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Comment: @PedsB can you try with `eval(str(myval))` as well to see if that works.

Comment: @PedsB or alternatively `import ast; ast.literal_eval(myval)`

Answer (score 0):

use `numpy`, conversion is quite simple:

```py
import numpy as np
myval = np.array([1.0, 0, 0, 0], dtype='<U14')

new_array = myval.astype(np.float).tolist()
```

notice I took " ' " out of your list, since you want to treat to it as a list and not as string. Then I converted it to float using numpy, and returned it to a regular list using `.tolist()`

About the format:
you read more about formats [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.3/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

"<" means it written in little-endian (google if your don't know the difference between little-endian and big-endian)

"U" means it's unicode

"16" means 14 bytes.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, myval is an example, I don't actually declare it as such. I guess it would have been more appropriate to say that myval evaluates to array('[1.0, 0, 0, 0]', dtype='<U14'), they are values I source from a csv.

Comment: so please clarify. You have csv, when you read it you receive an array with this format? and what you are trying to do?